# Soft-keyboard not closing

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

When I open my app using android search, the keyboard doesn't hide automatically.

I've already tried these two methods

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open my app using android search"?

Comment: @Nux In android, you can open app using android app search. When the app opens, the keyboard(which was used to type the app name) closes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)

 activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.

    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution as I have mentioned in the question
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);